# In NASM, does one usually use %define for typedefs?

Tags: nasm

For example:

```
%define char db
%define string db
%define float dd

  .section data
eol char `\n`
msg string "Message"
num float 1.2
```

Is this something I can do or should it be avoided for some reason? If so, is there a better alternative?

Comment: That's a matter of personal taste (or company standards if you happen to write assembly for a living, which I think is quite rare these days). I tend to use the names provided by the assembler and the include files for the APIs I'm using.

Comment: A subjective suggestion, but I'd make `string` a macro where a null terminating character is added at the end, but that's my option.